# Powershell writes first line but cannot write subsequent lines to file in for loop

Tags: powershell, file, for-loop, append

I have a nested `for` loop in which I am trying to write a new `line` of text to a [csv] file within the innermost loop.

For the life of me I can't get this to work. It writes the first line, but nothing else.
Powershell dutifully writes each line of text to the console, but no matter which file write method I choose it simply **REFUSES** to append *anything* else after the first line (`$headers`).

***What am I doing wrong?***

```powershell
$blob = "a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5"
$outfile = 'C:\myfile.txt'
$arr = @('1','2','3','4','5')

# try with Out-File -- FAILS
ForEach ($num in $arr) {
    If ($blob -match "(?<name>[^\s]) (?<num>$([regex]::Escape($num)))") {
        Write-Host $Matches.name $Matches.num -Separator "," |
        Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath "$outfile" -Append -Force
    }
}

# try with Add-Content -- FAILS
ForEach ($num in $arr) {
    If ($blob -match "(?<name>[^\s]) (?<num>$([regex]::Escape($num)))") {
        Write-Host $Matches.name $Matches.num -Separator "," |
        Add-Content -Encoding Ascii "$outfile"
    }
}

# try with Export-Csv -- FAILS
ForEach ($num in $arr) {
    If ($blob -match "(?<name>[^\s]) (?<num>$([regex]::Escape($num)))") {
        Write-Host $Matches.name $Matches.num -Separator "," |
        Export-Csv -Encoding ASCII -Force -Append -LiteralPath "$outfile"
    }
}
```

I have full write permission of file since I created it.
I do not believe this is a data type conflict (the real code is dealing only with strings).

This is driving me bonkers!

What is particularly ***incendiary*** is that if I copy the single inner loop line and manually execute that (while `$vars` are still in memory), it appends to the file >8O!

```powershell
Write-Host $Matches.name $Matches.num -Separator "," | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath "$outfile" -Append -Force
```

***What could possibly be the issue?***

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of those cmdlets can capture the output of `Write-Host` which goes to the information stream not to stdout. First of, remove `Write-Host` and try, see if that works.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Ok, thanks, but in my real script I want to make use of the `-Separator` argument of `Write-Host` to create a `TAB` separated string. I try what you suggest and report back.

Comment: You can use ```-join "`t"``` to join strings with tab.

Comment: How many different string object can I join with `-join`?

Comment: You mean how many elements of your array you can join with tab? The answer is all.

Comment: Thanks, your advice worked. Do you want to post an answer or shall I? You deserve the credit.

Comment: That's fine, you can post it, still I don't fully understand what you're trying to do but there is probably an simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on advice from @SantiagoSquarzon, this worked:

```powershell
$blob = "a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5"
$outfile = 'C:\myfile.txt'
$arr = @('1','2','3','4','5')

# try with Out-File -- FAILS
ForEach ($num in $arr) {
    If ($blob -match "(?<name>[^\s]) (?<num>$([regex]::Escape($num)))") {
        $Matches.name, $Matches.num, -Separator "," |
        Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath "$outfile" -Append -Force
    }
}
```